# why google_mobile_ads and flutter_native_admob is giving error

Tags: flutter, admob

please help i'm stuck here since many days.

when i use **google_mobile_ads** and **flutter_native_admob** package together it is showing

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':**app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses**'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbj found in modules jetified-play-services-measurement-17.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:17.1.0) and jetified-play-services-measurement-sdk-api-17.5.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api:17.5.0)`

and when i remove flutter_native_admob package my app running perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the android module `build.gradle` under `flutter_native_admob`:

API `'com.Google.Firebase:firebase-ads:19.0.0'`

For API `'com.Google.Android.GMS:play-services-ads: 19.7.0'`

The modified:
[image: The modified]